# How do I correctly repopulate a <sj:datepicker timepicker="true">?

Tags: jsp, struts2, datetimepicker, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm using the [Struts2-jQuery `Datepicker` with the `Timepicker` Addon](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag#Datepicker_with_Timepicker_Addon).

Assuming that a `java.util.Date` object is returned form an `Action` `getMyDate()` getter method:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
            timepickerFormat="HH:mm"
                  timepicker="true" 
                        name="myDate" />
```

This always results in the date being populated correctly, but the `timepicker` is always `00:00`.

Comment: It seemed to work but it's not. I've found the JIRA describing it as a bug, I'm now searching for a workaround solution to this before reopening the answer

Comment: Could you post a link to jira ticket. Maybe problem comes from specific format `HH:mm` try with `hh:mm`.

Comment: Which version of S2 jquery plugin? For me (with v3.7.0) your code with `<s:set var="myDate" value="new java.util.Date()"/>` is working fine.

Comment: LOL... the problem I had was the same of the [Issue 1057](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1057), I was sending a String but needed to parse a Date, not a String... so `name="myDateStr"` to a setter with parsing capabilities (if not using a converter) and `value="myDate"`. P.S: 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the time to expand the solution I've figured out on 18 december and briefly mentioned in the comments.

### The Problem

The `<sj:datepicker timepicker="true">` tag correctly parses a Date object, but not its String representation. **This is reported in [Issue 1057](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1057)**, with status accepted but still not fixed.

This **works**:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
                  timepicker="true" 
                       value="%{new java.util.Date()}" />
```

This **does NOT work**:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
                  timepicker="true" 
                       value="%{'07/01/2015 14:42'}" />
```

When not using a Converter, you need to send the format of the date-time to a `String` variable, instead than to a `Date` one:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
                  timepicker="true" 
                        name="dateStr" />
```

```java
private String dateStr; 
public void setDateStr(String dateStr){
    this.dateStr = dateStr;
}
public String getDateStr(){
    return dateStr;
}
```

If you need a Date (you probably do), you can use a String Getter and Setter, that will handle the parsing and the formatting between Date and String:

```java
private static final String FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";

private Date date; 
public void setDateStr(String dateStr){
    date = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT,Locale.ITALIAN).parse(dateStr);
}
public String getDateStr(){
    return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT,Locale.ITALIAN).format(date);
}
```

But both this methods, due to the bug linked above, won't work. The solution is so easy that made me laugh in my last comment to the question:

### The Solution

**Use a String setter, and a Date getter**, then it will work perfectly:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
                  timepicker="true" 
                        name="dateStr" 
                       value="date" />
```

```java
private Date date; 
public void setDateStr(String dateStr){
    date = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT,Locale.ITALIAN).parse(dateStr);
}
public Date getDate(){
    return date;
}
```

(or write a Converter).

<sub>**Side note**: `timepickerFormat="HH:mm"` is not needed because `HH:mm` (24 hours format) is already the default format. You need to change it only if you want the 12 hours display format.</sub>