# Exception occurs when I use <s:datetextfield /> tag in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, exception, struts2, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

When I use the tag

```xml
<s:datetextfield format="dd-MM-yyyy"></s:datetextfield>
```

(where s is a prefix for struts tag) I get an exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Template not found for name "/template/bootstrap/datetextfield.ftl".

Do I have to declare/instantiate some date format object and pass it ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using the [struts2-bootstrap-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28558436/1654265), with the **bootstrap theme**;

it also seems that [the bootstrap theme is unprovided of the freemarker template for the `<s:datetextfield />` tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-bootstrap/tree/master/struts2-bootstrap-plugin/src/main/resources/template/bootstrap).

Following the logic, the solution is to use a theme (for that tag only) that [is provided of the appropriate `.ftl`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/template/simple/datetext.ftl), in the following way:

```xml
<s:datetextfield format="dd-MM-yyyy" theme="simple" />
```

This however is a non-standard situation... it's the first time I see it happens. There is also a JIRA report about this, [WW-4434](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4434).

I'm not sure what that tag does since I've neved used it and the documentation is broken, but if it's just about textfields, dates and datepickers, consider using native HTML5 datepickers (`<s:textfield type="date"/>`) with [appropriate fallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503903/1654265).

Comment: fyi: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3493 and https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/plugins/javatemplates/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/views/java/simple/DateTextFieldHandler.java.

Comment: Thank you @AleksandrM . God, what an ugly tag :D

Comment: Yes. I am using bootstrap-plugin. I have to use it because I don't have much time to work on the UI

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Finally I used <s:textfield type="date"/> for HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and solved it this way:

```
<s:textfield name="date" type="date"
                     format="dd-MM-yyyy" label="BirthDate" />
```